# How to serialize C# objects to generate specific JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am trying to create JSON like the following to pass to an external via TCP.

> {"method": "dither", "params": [10, false, {"pixels": 1.5, "time": 8, "timeout": 40}], "id": 42}

I came close, but this is what I got instead:

> {"method": "dither", "params": [10, false,**"**{"pixels": 1.5, "time": 8, "timeout": 40}**"**], "id": 42}

Notice the quote marks around the 3rd element of the params array.

I would appreciate any help in resolving this. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml;
using System.Reflection;

namespace DitherTest
{
    [CollectionDataContract]
    public class DitherParametersList : ArrayList
    {
        public DitherParametersList() : base()
        {}
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Dither
    {
        [DataMember( Name="method", Order=1)]
        public string Method { get; set; }

        [DataMember( Name="params", Order=2)]
        public DitherParametersList Parameters { get; set; }

        [DataMember( Name="id", Order=3)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract( Namespace="")]
    public class Settle
    {
        [DataMember( Name = "pixels" )]
        public double Pixels { get; set; }
        [DataMember( Name = "time" )]
        public int Time { get; set; }
        [DataMember( Name = "timeout" )]
        public int Timeout { get; set; }

        public string SerializeJson()
        {
            return this.ToJSON();
        }
    }

    static class Extensions
    {
        public static string ToJSON<T>( this T obj ) where T : class
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer( typeof( T ) );
            using ( MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream() )
            {
                serializer.WriteObject( stream, obj );
                return Encoding.Default.GetString( stream.ToArray() );
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            double ditherAmount = 10.0;
            bool ditherRaOnly = false;

            Settle settle = new Settle { Pixels = 1.5, Time = 8, Timeout = 40 };
            DitherParametersList parameterList = new DitherParametersList();
            parameterList.Add( ditherAmount );
            parameterList.Add( ditherRaOnly );
            string settleStr = settle.SerializeJson();
            parameterList.Add( settleStr );

            Dither dither = new Dither { Method = "dither", Parameters = parameterList, Id=42 };

            string temp = dither.ToJSON();


        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Validate your JSON using http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: To generate C# classes based on JSON format, you can use - http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: first and foremost - use json.net for json in c#. Thats what MS uses in most places now

Comment: Try this: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json, ditch `DataContractJsonSerializer `

Answer (score 1):

you told it to make the third arg a string. You serialized it to a string then stuck it in as an arg.

you need

```
parameterList.Add( settle );
```

Comment: He wants it to be a string. Check his question. I suspect a bug in the deserializer he is using.

Comment: my reading is that he wants it like the first line in the question

Comment: No, I don't think that I want it to be a string.  That is probably why the quotes are there.

Comment: After 're-rereading' the question, you are probably correct. Let him clarify his question.

Comment: Lol then WTH did you do this? `string settleStr = settle.SerializeJson();` ?? Just add `settle` straight away like @pm100 suggested.

Comment: When my class(es) are serialized I want the JSON to appear as the first fragment of my original post.

If I change as recommended to add the settle object to the parameterList I get the following error:

Type 'DitherTest.Settle' with data contract name 'Settle:' is not expected. 

If I then add a [KnownType( typeof(Settle))] attribute to the Dither class definition the generated JSON is as as follows:

{"method": "dither", "params": [10 ,false, {"__type": "Settle", "pixels":1.5,"time": 8, "timeout": 40}],"id": 42}

Again, not what I need.

Comment: serailize using json.net

Answer (score 1):

First of all, be sure to use [newtonsoft.com/json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) like [pm100](https://stackoverflow.com/users/173397/pm100) mentioned in his comment.
I've changed your code so that it would work with newtonsoft.json and got exactly what you've asked for:

```
{"method": "dither", "params": [10, false, {"pixels": 1.5, "time": 8, "timeout": 40}], "id": 42}
```

I removed the DitherParametersList you've created and used those models:

```
public class Dither
{
    [JsonProperty("method", Order = 1)]
    public string Method { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("params", Order = 2)]
    public ArrayList Parameters { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id", Order = 3)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Settle
{
    [JsonProperty("pixels")]
    public double Pixels { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("time")]
    public int Time { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("timeout")]
    public int Timeout { get; set; }
}
```

And serialized them easily:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var settle = new Settle { Pixels = 1.5, Time = 8, Timeout = 40 };
        var parameterList = new ArrayList { 10, false, settle };
        var dither = new Dither { Method = "dither", Parameters = parameterList, Id = 42 };

        string temp = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dither);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what I need cannot be done with the MS serializer?

Comment: as will-ray stated, you can trim the quotes:
    string settleStr = settle.SerializeJson().Trim('"');
But it's definitely not the right way to go.

Comment: Sure, feel free to choose my answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The quotes are coming from the first serialization that you did here:

```
string settleStr = settle.SerializeJson();
```

Assuming that you want to avoid using the Newtonsoft library, an immediate fix would be to simply trim them off:

```
string settleStr = settle.SerializeJson().Trim('"');
```

A more robust solution would only require serialization one time. If you used a `List{string}` instead of a `DitherParamtersList`, you could do this:

```
Settle settle = new Settle { Pixels = 1.5, Time = 8, Timeout = 40 };
var parameterList = new List<string>()
{
    ditherAmount.ToString(),
    ditherRaOnly.ToString(),
    string.Join(",", settle.Pixels, settle.Time, settle.Timeout)
};

Dither dither = new Dither { Method = "dither", Parameters = parameterList, Id = 42 };

string temp = dither.ToJSON();
```

Comment: Thanks, I opted for the Newtonsoft library...Problem solved.